# SIM808L 2.0 won't connect to Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have an Arduino Uno and a SIM808L 2.0 module.

I want to connect the module to the Arduino, but I can't. It displays 'not working' (you can see in the picture)

[image: scheme02]

[image: scheme01]

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial sim(10, 11);

void setup() {
  delay(7000);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(9600);
  sim.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("working");
  } else {
    Serial.println("not working")
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "It enter in the if:" mean? Please [edit] and clarify your question.

Comment: what does this have to do with robotics?

Comment: Pictures aren't clear, but are you sure your wires are connected correctly? The red wire in the Arduino Uno board looks like it's plugged into GND to me.

Comment: Yes. It is surely connected. I tried many options